# How to build dynamic SQL with using

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to make dynamic `sql` like this  `'select col1,col2 from '|| my_table ||'` it works fine but I want to write like this `sql_stmt:='select col1,col2 from :myTable';  execute immediate sql_stmt using  my_table;` but I have error I have same error when I want to do something like this  tooo `v_filter := my_proc();   sql_stmt:='select col1,col2 from my_table where :filter' execute immediate sql_stmt using v_filter;` is it impossible to build dynamic `sql` like this  with `using` ? If it is impossible what is another way to avoid `sql injections`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use table names in dynamic SQL, yes - you'll have to concatenate them. In order to avoid SQL injection, use DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_table in varchar2) is
  2    l_table varchar2(30);
  3    l_str   varchar2(200);
  4    l_cnt   number;
  5  begin
  6    l_table := dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table);
  7
  8    l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || par_table;
  9    execute immediate (l_str) into l_cnt;
 10    dbms_output.put_line('Table contains ' || l_cnt || ' rows');
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> exec p_test('dept');
Table contains 4 rows

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_test('delete from emp');
BEGIN p_test('delete from emp'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-44002: invalid object name
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 316
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

**[EDIT: WHERE clause]**

This works:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_table in varchar2,
  2                                      par_filter in varchar2) is
  3    l_table varchar2(30);
  4    l_str   varchar2(200);
  5    l_cnt   number;
  6  begin
  7    l_table := dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table);
  8
  9    l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || par_table ||
 10             ' where deptno = :filter';
 11    execute immediate (l_str) into l_cnt using par_filter;
 12    dbms_output.put_line('Table contains ' || l_cnt || ' rows');
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test('emp', '10');
Table contains 3 rows

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

WHERE clause, modified so that it contains only the WHERE keyword, while the rest is to be used as a parameter:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_table in varchar2,
  2                                      par_filter in varchar2) is
  3    l_table varchar2(30);
  4    l_str   varchar2(200);
  5    l_cnt   number;
  6  begin
  7    l_table := dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table);
  8
  9    l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || par_table ||
 10             ' where :filter';
 11    execute immediate (l_str) into l_cnt using par_filter;
 12    dbms_output.put_line('Table contains ' || l_cnt || ' rows');
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test('emp', 'deptno = 10');
BEGIN p_test('emp', 'deptno = 10'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

It won't work; is that what you're asking?

Some more reading about [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/dynamic.htm) on Oracle, as well as here, on Stack overflow ([How can I create a dynamic WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514254/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-where-clause).

Comment: It works fine for table name and how about where clause where I want to concatenate statement with filter ?